# How to display thread group name in JMeter log and in step

Tags: logging, jmeter

I have a problem when I run many tests in the same time in a single test plan.
the problem is that in the logs I saw errors but I can not figure out to which test they belongs to. (all the tests have some common steps).

1. How can I see in logs to which test it refers to?
2. I want in the name of the step to write the name of test, but not manually, is there a function to write the test name.
   for example if the test name is "add to array yellow", and the step name is "add one".

I would like to call the test add to array yellow + add one.

Is it possible in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should have `threadName` column in the .jtl results file which contains thread group name, thread number and iteration number

[image: JMeter JTL Results File]

This should provide you enough information regarding which sampler has failed.

If you don't see `threadName` column in the .jtl results file - something is wrong with your [result save configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults), to enable saving thread name you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
```

More information: [Useful JMeter Properties: Save Results. Save the World](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/useful-jmeter-properties-save-results-save-world)

Comment: @ Dmitri still the problem is with exceptions in the log, not the results, in results I see pass or not pass,  and the log is full with exceptions. in the csv not mentioned any exception, if I run 100 tests and all the log is with exceptions how Can I tell to whiche test? I want to export the error log not just the results of Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Test Plan should be get using `${__TestPlanName}`.

Step name should be get using `${__samplerName()}`

so you can use `${__TestPlanName} ${__samplerName()}`

To get Thread Group Name In JSR223 Element you can use

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().getName()
```

Comment: OK  can I get the thread group name, I created a test plan and each test is actual thread group, Can I get this name? (not the number the name)?

Comment: I just want in the error log to understand on which test (thread group) it failed, and way, currently Jmeter log just displayed the step that it failed but not mentioned on which thread group it failed, if I have 1000 tests and in all of them the same step, how can I know where to check the error?

Comment: In JSR223 Element you can use `ctx.getThreadGroup().getName();`

Comment: Yes I know the problem is this, I have 100 thread groups (meaning tests)  and they have some common steps, when Jmeter throw error or exception it not tell the thread, so how can I know if I run all the tests together which test failed? to which thread group the error apply to?